# How to fix the error of type-mismatch and trailing spaces in C

Tags: c, whitespace, type-mismatch, removing-whitespace

This was my school assignment and the feedback from the professor says violates the rule of type-mismatch and also avoid trailing spaces. I couldn't still pinpoint the exact problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SECS_PER_HOUR 3600 //1 hour = 60mins * 60 secs = 3600 secs
#define METERS_PER_MILE 1600 
int main()
{
    double distance, time, speedmph, speedmps;

    scanf("%lf", &distance);
    scanf("%lf", &time);

    speedmph = distance / time;
    speedmps = (speedmph * METERS_PER_MILE) / SECS_PER_HOUR;

    printf("\nThe speed is %.2f miles per hour. \n", speedmph);
    printf("The speed is %.2f meters per second. \n\n", speedmps);

    main();
}
```

Comment: `%1f` (number one) doesn't seem right to me. Perhaps you meant `%lf` (letter ell). And I guess the prof doesn't want to see the space before the newline character (`\n`).

Comment: Sorry but in the submission i used %.2f because we had to get output with two decimal point. Is that what caused a type mismatch?

Comment: Aside from the corrections that @user3386109 indicated, why is `main()` calling itself recursively? Run through a few (ok, on most systems a few thousand) iterations and you will run out of resources. The program should simply be wrapped in a `while` loop, perhaps with an exit if `time=0`.

Comment: As for the type mismatch, the issue must be declaring your variables as `double` but only using them as `float`.

Comment: The professor may expect `%.2lf`. For `printf` `%.2f` and `%.2lf` do exactly the same thing, but if the professor wants to see `%.2lf`, then that's what you need to do.

Comment: BTW, @daShier is right about the call to `main();` on the last line of the code. That needs to be removed.

Comment: So is that a type-mismatch if I use %.2f instead of %.2lf?

Comment: Thanks @daShier I will remove the main(); at the end of the code

Comment: Technically no, at least for modern compilers. When the professor was learning the language, using `%.2lf` with `printf` may have been required.

Comment: @daShier The compiler may make that a tail-call optimized call, so you won’t run out of stack-space - but it isn’t guaranteed.

Comment: @Dai, While modern compilers are amazing in their ability to realize what a programmer was (probably) thinking, I don't believe that a student should be learning to rely on the compiler to undo bad habits. ;)

Comment: @daShier it’s unfortunate that C doesn’t reify the call system to enable opt-in explicit tail-calls. Doing so would make recursive functions much easier to read and write.

Comment: Your professor should state the rules clearly and precisely. If they have not, ask them to do so. If they have, edit the rules into your question. Without this, your question is unclear and cannot be properly answered.

Comment: Clearly the error is that there are [1609 metres in a mile](https://www.google.com/search?q=meters+per+mile) (to the nearest metre).

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your code should look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SECS_PER_HOUR 3600 // 1 hour = 60mins * 60 secs = 3600 secs
#define METERS_PER_MILE 1600

int main(void)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        double distance;
        double time;
        double speedmph;
        double speedmps;

        scanf("%lf", &distance);
        scanf("%lf", &time);

        speedmph = distance / time;
        speedmps = (speedmph * METERS_PER_MILE) / SECS_PER_HOUR;

        printf("\nThe speed is %.2lf miles per hour.\n", speedmph);
        printf("The speed is %.2lf meters per second.\n\n", speedmps);
    }
}
```

Changes are:

1. Separate unrelated lines by one empty line.
2. Indent the source to reflect the structure.
3. Define each variable in its own line. This improves readability and is good habit to avoid problems if you define pointers in other programs.
4. Concerning **type mismatch**: Change `%.2f` into `%.2lf` to match the `double`. However, as @user3386109 wrote, for `printf()` its the same. If there were some `float` it would be casted to a `double`.
5. Concerning **trailing spaces**: Remove blanks before `\n`.
6. Add endless loop to avoid stack overflow (no pun intended) if the compiler does not realize tail recursion.